# How can I view my reviews on Amazon?

Tags: account-management, amazon

I'd like to view my reviews on Amazon.

Does anybody know how can do that?

How I can see all my reviews on Amazon?

Note: I have had to make this question a bit repetitive because the simple question of "I'd like to view my reviews on Amazon" with similar one or even two line body, gets flagged as "this question does not meet our quality standards"

**Added  19th november 2019**

I can't see a profile option where the option would be to see reviews

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can view your reviews from your profile

- go to your profile by clicking on your name
- click on **Profile** under **Ordering and shopping preferences** section
- find the review you want to view
- and view it, edit it or delete a review you wish

Comment: where is the link to my profile?

Comment: ok I think I got it,  I click on "hello.[name] your account] Then the word "profile" is under "Ordering and shopping preferences"

Comment: the rest of your answer is clear. Can you add to your answer re how to get to the profile?

Comment: @barlop done...

Comment: Maybe your amazon is designed differently to mine.  I click my name, then I don't "select" ordering and shopping preferences, it's not a link.  After clicking my name I can do find-on-page, and I see the word "profile" appears as a link in a section called "ordering and shopping preferences" but that's just a section title not something to click or "select".  Having clicked name, I click "profile"(which happens to be listed as a link under that section titled "ordering and shopping preferences"), and I see the reviews.

Comment: that's better    __

Comment: They changed it. I no longer see the option.. I've included a screenshot. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

1. Click on "Accounts and Lists" near the top right-hand corner
2. Click "Your Account"
3. Look at the "Ordering and Shopping Preferences" box and click on "Your Amazon Profile"
4. Click on your review under "Community Activity"

Note: If there is nothing there, your review is still being processed

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't show the entire history of reviews. It only goes back a few months. I'm looking for a review I wrote a couple years ago. I used to be able to find it, but I can no longer see how.

Answer (score 3):

**Here is the correct order of steps with accurate menu labels as of Feb 2020:**

1. On the upper right hover (don't click) on "Hello USERNAME".
2. It will open a menu. Select "Your Account".
3. This will open a new page. Go to the "Ordering and Shopping preferences" and select "Your Amazon Profile".

Comment: THIS IS THE CORRECT WAY TO FIND IT, at least on my account. Don't know why it had only 1 vote. Maybe Amazon tests different user interfaces on different people.

Answer (score 3):

Just [click here](https://www.amazon.com/gp/profile), it's under "Community activity".

You can also filter using the combo box that says **View: All Activity**, change it to **View: Reviews** to see only your reviews.

Comment: None of the other solutions above worked for me. Yours did!!! Thank you!

Comment: I concur. This is the correct answer to finding your reviews.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the app:

1. Click on the three lines in the upper-left corner.
2. Click on “Your Account”
3. Scroll down to the bottom. The second to last bold heading is “Personalized Content”.
4. Select “Profile” beneath that.
5. Scroll to bottom to see your reviews. You can filter the activity by reviews only.

Comment: It only shows me my last 20 reviews. I have 196 total.

Comment: I'm still trying to figure this out. crap!!!